# commons-cli dependent arguments

Tags: apache-commons-cli

I use apache commons-cli for a command line tool.
I have pairs of dependent arguments, e.g argument B makes sense only if argument A is present.
That will have 2 benefits : automatic warning/error and a more usefull usage statment .
Does commons-cli support it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not; you have to enforce such things manually.  CLI has [OptionGroup](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionGroup.html)s, but they are purely mutually exclusive options, not dependent options.  See JavaDoc for [Option](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/Option.html), [OptionBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder.html) (which I highly recommend using) and the previously mentioned OptionGroup.